# How to recognize the obfuscator type/algorithm by its encoded code?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have an obfuscated code in javascript, is there a way to recognize what type or algorithm it uses? cause popular deobfuscators dont do the work...?

part of the obfuscated code:

```
window.pvy=!!window.pvy;try{(function(){try{var Zz,sz,Iz=1,lz=1,Lz=1,ZZ=1,jZ=1,JZ=1,OZ=1;for(var zs=0;zs<sz;++zs)Iz+=2,lz+=2,Lz+=2,ZZ+=2,jZ+=2,JZ+=2,OZ+=3;Zz=Iz+lz+Lz+ZZ+jZ+JZ+OZ;window.JJ===Zz&&(window.JJ=++Zz)}catch(zzz){window.JJ=Zz}var Ss=!0;function is(z){z&&(Ss=!1,document.cookie="brav=ad");return Ss}function Is(z){is(z);return!0}function os(){}is(window[os.name]===os);is("function"!==typeof ie9rgb4);is(/\x3c/.test(function(){return"\x3c"})&!/x3d/.test(function(){return"'x3'+'d';"}));
var Os=window.attachEvent||/mobi/i.test(window["\x6e\x61vi\x67a\x74\x6f\x72"]["\x75\x73e\x72A\x67\x65\x6et"]),zS=+new Date+6E5,ZS,SS,iS=setTimeout,IS=Os?3E4:6E3;function s(){if(!document.querySelector)return!0;var z=+new Date,S=z>zS;if(S)return is(!1);S=SS&&ZS+IS<z;S=is(S);ZS=z;SS||(SS=!0,iS(function(){SS=!1},1));return S}s();var jS=[17795081,27611931586,1558153217];
function lS(z){z="string"===typeof z?z:z.toString(36);var S=window[z];if(!S.toString)return;var Z=""+S;window[z]=function(z,Z){SS=!1;return S(z,Z)};window[z].toString=function(){return Z}}for(var LS=0;LS<jS.length;++LS)lS(jS[LS]);is(!1!==window.pvy);var oS=[is,Is];
(function szz(){if(!s())return;var S=!1;function Z(Z){for(var S=0;Z--;)S+=J(document.documentElement,null);return S}function J(Z,S){var O="vi";S=S||new l;return Jz(Z,function(Z){Z.setAttribute("data-"+O,S.Il_());return J(Z,S)},null)}function l(){this.JZS=1;this.lJS=0;this.Is=this.JZS;this.c=null;this.Il_=function(){this.c=this.lJS+this.Is;if(!isFinite(this.c))return this.reset(),this.Il_();this.lJS=this.Is;this.Is=this.c;this.c=null;return this.Is};this.reset=function(){this.JZS++;this.lJS=0;this.Is=
this.JZS}}var O=!1;function zz(Z,S){if(!s())return;var J=document.createElement(Z);S=S||document.body;S.appendChild(J);J&&J.style&&(J.style.display="none");s()}function _z(Z,J){if(!s())return;J=J||Z;var l="|";function zz(Z){Z=Z.split(l);var S=[];for(var J=0;J<Z.length;++J){var O="",Oz=Z[J].split(",");for(var iz=0;iz<Oz.length;++iz)O+=Oz[iz][iz];S.push(O)}return S}var _z=0,SZ="datalist,details,embed,figure,hrimg,strong,article,formaddress|audio,blockquote,area,source,input|canvas,form,link,tbase,option,details,article";
SZ.split(l);SZ=zz(SZ);SZ=new RegExp(SZ.join(l),"g");while(SZ.exec(Z))SZ=new RegExp((""+new Date)[8],"g"),S&&(O=s()),++_z;return s()?J(_z&&1):void 0}function Jz(Z,S,J){if(!s())return;(J=J||O)&&zz("div",Z);Z=Z.children;var l=0;for(var _z in Z){J=Z[_z];try{J instanceof HTMLElement&&(S(J),++l)}catch(SZ){}}return s()?l:void 0}_z(szz,Z);s()})();var OS=88,z_,Z_={_S:!1};
function s_(){if(!s())return;!(1+Math.random())&&new Date%3&&arguments.callee();var z=33,S,Z,J,l;Z_._S&&(l=window[L(27612545633,z)])&&(J=Array[L(72697618120913,z)][L(48032765,z)][L(573576,z)](arguments,_(898)?0:parseInt(0+[],10)),S=J[L(1294399172,z)],Z=J[S-(_(905)?0:parseInt(1+[]+[],10))],(Z=typeof Z===L(1442151714,z)&&S>(_(358)?0:parseInt(1+[]+[],10))&&Z)&&J[L(1736046845,z)](S-(_(947)?0:parseInt(1+[]+[],10)),_(36)?parseInt(1+[]+[],10):0),!Z||Z<=(_(567)?1:2))&&(typeof l.log[L(17995717,z)]==L(1242178186166,
z)?l.log[L(17995717,z)](l,J):l.log(J[_(756)?0:parseInt(0+[],10)]));s()}function S_(z){if(Z_._S)throw z;}function Szz(){var z=77;return!!window[L(1698633989514,z)]!==Ss?(s_(I(z,142,187,193,182,122,177,178,175,194,180,180,182,187,180,109,179,188,194,187,177,109,175,198,109,188,175,179,194,192,176,174,193,188,191)),_(897)?0:parseInt(1+[]+[],10)):(_(444),0)}
function i_(z){if(!s())return;!(1+Math.random())&&new Date%3&&arguments.callee();var S=45;if(!Z_._S)return function(){Math.random()};z=(z+I(S,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77))[L(1743991938,S)]((_(14),0),_(507)?15:12);return s()?function(Z,J){if(!s())return;1+Math.random()||(arguments[4]="udpugt");typeof J!==L(86464843759048,S)?(Z+=I(S,103,77),s_(I(S,136)+z+I(S,138,77)+Z,J,_(886)?0:parseInt(0+[],10))):s_(I(S,136)+z+I(S,138,77)+Z);s()}:void 0}
function j_(z){if(!s())return;var S=90,Z;Z=""+I(S,188,187,189,197,193,204,201,207,200,190,135,189,201,198,201,204,148,204,191,190,149);Z+=I(S,189,201,198,201,204,148,209,194,195,206,191,149);Z+=I(S,192,201,200,206,135,209,191,195,193,194,206,148,188,201,198,190,149);Z+=I(S,202,187,190,190,195,200,193,148,143,202,210,149);s_(I(S,127,189,159,172,172,169,172,148,122)+z,Z);s()}
Z_._S&&function(){if(!s())return;!(1+Math.random())&&new Date%3&&arguments.callee();var z=94;function S(){var S=Date[L(30610,z)]()-zz;S>l+O&&s_(I(z,181,159,176,172,167,172,165,152,126,213,191,210,193,198,194,205,197,126,213,191,199,210,195,194,126)+(S-O)+L(726,z));Z()}function Z(){if(!(s()&&1+Math.random()))return;window[J]?(l=window[J],zz=Date[L(30610,z)](),setTimeout(S,O)):setTimeout(Z,O);s()}var J=I(z,181,159,178,161,166,162,173,165),l=_(493)?132:150,O=_(356)?72:50,zz;Z();s()}();
var L_=function(z,S){function Z(){1+Math.random()||(arguments[2]="cdf9ll")}if(!s())return;var J=21,l={},O=l.jz={},zz=O.L1S={extend:function(z){if(!s())return;Z[L(72697618120925,J)]=this;var S=new Z;z&&S[I(J,130,126,141,94,131)](z);S[I(J,125,118,136,100,140,131,101,135,132,133,122,135,137,142)](L(870272,J))||(S[L(870272,J)]=function(){S.sO_[L(870272,J)][L(17995729,J)](this,arguments)});S[L(870272,J)][L(72697618120925,J)]=S;S.sO_=this;return s()?S:void 0},create:function(){var z=this[L(903325780,J)]();
z[L(870272,J)][L(17995729,J)](z,arguments);return z},"\u0069n\x69t":function(){},"\u006di\x78In":function(z){for(var Z in z)z[I(J,125,118,136,100,140,131,101,135,132,133,122,135,137,142)](Z)&&(this[Z]=z[Z]);z[I(J,125,118,136,100,140,131,101,135,132,133,122,135,137,142)](I(J,137,132,104,137,135,126,131,124))&&(this[I(J,137,132,104,137,135,126,131,124)]=z[I(J,137,132,104,137,135,126,131,124)])},clone:function(){if(!s())return;1+Math.random()||
(arguments[3]="f7f8ub");return s()?this[L(870272,J)][L(72697618120925,J)][L(903325780,J)](this):void 0}},_z=O.l2=zz[L(903325780,J)]({"\u0069\x6e\u0069\x74":function(z,Z){z=this.J_=z||[];this.JS=Z!=S?Z:(_(723)?3:4)*z[L(1294399184,J)]},toString:function(z){return(z||Sz)[L(81323539083337,J)](this)},concat:function(z){if(!s())return;var Z=this.J_,S=z.J_,l=this.JS;z=z.JS;this.l_();if(l%(_(903),4))for(var O=_(530)?0:parseInt(0+[],10);O<z;O++)Z[l+
O>>>(_(642)?1:2)]=Z[l+O>>>(_(108),2)]|(S[O>>>(_(132),2)]>>>(_(253)?24:26)-(_(335)?11:8)*(O%(_(810)?5:4))&(_(534)?140:255))<<(_(460)?34:24)-(_(253)?8:10)*((l+O)%(_(513)?3:4));else if((_(797)?39502:65535)<S[L(1294399184,J)])for(O=(_(228),0);O<z;O+=_(824)?5:4)Z[l+O>>>(_(404),2)]=S[O>>>(_(39)?2:1)];else Z[L(1206284,J)][L(17995729,J)](Z,S);this.JS+=z;return s()?this:void 0},l_:function(){!(1+Math.random())&&new Date%3&&arguments.callee();var Z=this.J_,S=this.JS;Z[S>>>(_(831),2)]=Z[S>>>(_(675),2)]&(_(990)?
2147483647:4294967295)<<(_(352)?43:32)-(_(605)?10:8)*(S%(_(663)?2:4));Z[L(1294399184,J)]=z[L(578664,J)](S/(_(51)?4:2))},clone:function(){1+Math.random()||(arguments[3]="51shwb");var z=zz[L(21167093,J)][L(573588,J)](this);z.J_=this.J_[L(48032777,J)]((_(120),0));return z},random:function(Z){if(!(s()&&1+Math.random()))return;for(var S=[],l=_(91)?parseInt(0+[],10):0;l<Z;l+=(_(453),4))S[L(1206284,J)]((_(878)?2147483647:4294967296)*z[L(1650473713,J)]()|(_(433)?0:parseInt(0+[],10)));return s()?new (_z[L(870272,
J)])(S,Z):void 0}}),Jz=l.Ji={},Sz=Jz.O5S={stringify:function(z){var Z=z.J_;z=z.JS;for(var S=[],l=_(214)?parseInt(0+[],10):0;l<z;l++){var O=Z[l>>>(_(305)?2:1)]>>>(_(563)?25:24)-(_(134)?8:7)*(l%(_(608)?3:4))&(_(693)?203:255);S[L(1206284,J)]((O>>>(_(318),4))[I(J,137,132,104,137,135,126,131,124)](_(529)?21:16));S[L(1206284,J)]((O&(_(946)?13:15))[I(J,137,132,104,137,135,126,131,124)](_(601)?22:16))}return S[L(918218,J)]("")},parse:function(z){1+Math.random()||(arguments[4]="r6rfay");for(var Z=z[L(1294399184,
J)],S=[],l=_(136)?parseInt(0+[],10):0;l<Z;l+=(_(625),2))S[l>>>(_(249)?3:2)]=S[l>>>(_(480),3)]|parseInt(z[L(1743991962,J)](l,_(838)?1:2),_(567)?13:16)<<(_(850)?34:24)-(_(543)?2:4)*(l%(_(909)?5:8));return new (_z[L(870272,J)])(S,Z/(_(207),2))}},iz=Jz.Js_={stringify:function(z){var Z=z.J_;z=z.JS;for(var S=[],l=_(216)?parseInt(0+[],10):0;l<z;l++)S[L(1206284,J)](String[I(J,123,135,132,130,88,125,118,135,88,132,121,122)](Z[l>>>(_(37),2)]>>>(_(748)?33:24)-(_(503)?9:8)*(l%(_(395),4))&(_(600)?163:255)));return S[L(918218,
J)]("")},parse:function(z){1+Math.random()||(arguments[0]="6kfucq");for(var Z=z[L(1294399184,J)],S=[],l=_(853)?0:parseInt(0+[],10);l<Z;l++)S[l>>>(_(901),2)]=S[l>>>(_(342)?1:2)]|(z[I(J,120,125,118,135,88,132,121,122,86,137)](l)&(_(990)?234:255))<<(_(507)?12:24)-(_(880)?4:8)*(l%(_(202),4));return new (_z[L(870272,J)])(S,Z)}},jz=Jz.L1_={stringify:function(z){if(!s())return;1+Math.random()||(arguments[2]="rkqv50");try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(iz[L(81323539083337,J)](z)))}catch(Z){throw Error(I(J,
98,118,129,123,132,135,130,122,121,53,106,105,91,66,77,53,121,118,137,118));}s()},parse:function(z){return iz[L(42492953,J)](unescape(encodeURIComponent(z)))},OZi:function(z){return z+J_+l_}},Oz=O.Iz_=zz[L(903325780,J)]({reset:function(){1+Math.random()||(arguments[2]="jwv4gf");this.so=new (_z[L(870272,J)]);this.JJS=_(257)?parseInt(0+[],10):0},L2:function(z){L(1743045655,J)==typeof z&&(z=jz[L(42492953,J)](z));this.so[L(766993904,J)](z);this.JJS+=z.JS},SO:function(Z){if(!s())return;var S=this.so,l=
S.J_,O=S.JS,zz=this.oJ,jz=O/((_(250)?4:3)*zz),jz=Z?z[L(578664,J)](jz):z[L(28884,J)]((jz|(_(108),0))-this.iS_,_(166)?parseInt(0+[],10):0);Z=jz*zz;O=z[L(29162,J)]((_(912)?3:4)*Z,O);if(Z){for(var Oz=(_(319),0);Oz<Z;Oz+=zz)this.jJS(l,Oz);Oz=l[L(1736046857,J)](_(760)?0:parseInt(0+[],10),Z);S.JS-=O}return s()?new (_z[L(870272,J)])(Oz,O):void 0},clone:function(){var z=zz[L(21167093,J)][L(573588,J)](this);z.so=this.so[L(21167093,J)]();return z},iS_:_(642)?0:parseInt(0+[],10)});O.Is_=Oz[L(903325780,J)]({iS:zz[L(903325780,
J)](),"\u0069\x6e\u0069\x74":function(z){1+Math.random()||(arguments[4]="dmmj0g");this.iS=this.iS[L(903325780,J)](z);this[L(46039616,J)]()},reset:function(){Oz[L(46039616,J)][L(573588,J)](this);this.zZ()},update:function(z){this.L2(z);this.SO();return this},LL:function(z){z&&this.L2(z);return this.o2()},oJ:_(156)?16:9,"\u005fcreateHelper":function(z){return function(Z,S){return(new (z[L(870272,J)])(S)).LL(Z)}},J0_:function(z){return function(Z,
```

Comment: Deobfuscators can only do so much, the rest you need to do your self through prettyprinting and renaming/refactoring. Although theres more that deobfuscators could do here, the encoded strings jump out at me.

Comment: @NickA how can I rename the encoded part of code?

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't post the complete code. It's pretty likely that the actual unpacking happens in the very end.